# Is the $\sup(f(A))=f(\sup(A))?$

Tags: real-analysis

I just had my second class of Real Analysis, and our professor asked us to think about whether the $\sup(f(A)) = f(\sup(A))$ if $f:{\Bbb R} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}$, and $A \subset {\Bbb R}$.

My first instinct is to say no, since I can come up with a counter-example. 
If $f(x) = -x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ then $f(\sup(A)) = -1$ whereas $\sup(f(A)) = 0$.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could let me know if I'm on the right track. I'm just getting started with $\sup$'s and $\inf$'s.

Comment: That is a perfectly acceptable counterexample.  Your instinct was correct.

Comment: As an additional exercise that you might be interested in trying to prove/disprove, is the same question but with the added condition that $f$ is a monotonic increasing function.

Comment: I want to say yes to the second exercise, but I'll put more thought into it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JMoravitz and whether $f$ is continuous or not, and whether we're looking at an open or closed interval.